# Yii2 datepicker не работает

Tags: php, yii2, datepicker

Всем привет. Пытаюсь в форму добавить поле ввода времени. Для этого подключил yii\jui\DatePicker через команду `php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui "*"`. После этого обновил `php composer.phar update`. Произвел подключение виджета в шаблоне и создал поле с помощью Active Form. Но поле так и осталось прежним. Не могу понять в чем дело.

Вот сам шаблон:

```
<?php
use \yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\jui\DatePicker;
$form = ActiveForm::begin();    
?>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 well">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <?= $form->field($order_model,'bathhouse')->label('Номер бани')->dropDownList([
                                                                                        '1' => 1,
                                                                                        '2' => 2,
                                                                                        '3' => 3,
                                                                                        '4' => 4,
                                                                                        '5' => 5,
                                                                                        '6' => 6,
                                                                                    ]);?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <?= $form->field($order_model,'client_name')->label('Клиент')->textInput()?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?= $form->field($order_model, 'duration')->label('Время захода')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
                            'language' => 'ru',
                            'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                        ]) ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Создать</button>
</div>
<?php
    ActiveForm::end();
?>
</div>
```

В базовом шаблоне подключение скриптов следующее и никакие другие не используются:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/css/bootstrap/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Widget DatePicker подключает яваскрипт свой его нет в представленном вами куске поэтому и не работает. Почему нет надо смотреть не "отключен" ли вывод assets и т. п.